# XSLT Numeric order from Position ()

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been testing different solutions but cant wrap my head around how to get it to work with Position(). Have been looking on different examples but I dont really understand how the Position method works. 
Perhaps someone can use my example and explain it a little better.

So I have this collection of Car's

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="uppgift2.xsl"?>
<autoads>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Honda</name>
        <model>XL 1000 V</model>
        <regyear>2001</regyear>
        <price>129900</price>
        <adtext>2001 Honda XL 1000 V, 8.900 km. hög vindruta. Pris 129.900kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Nissan</name>
        <model>Almera 1.4S</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>119000</price>
        <adtext>1997 Nissan Almera 1.4S, 5 dörrar, met, 70.000 km. el.spegel/fönster, galv. kaross, c.lås, startspärr, airbag, nedfällb. baks. ABS, ute temp. R/CD, alarm, d.fäste, v.säten, s/v-hj.  EU-godk. full service, servo. Pris 119.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>5 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Mercedes-Benz</name>
        <model>C220 Elegance</model>
        <regyear>1995</regyear>
        <price>209000</price>
        <adtext>1995 Mercedes-Benz C220 Elegance, 4 dörrar, 88.000 km. skinn, klima/automatic, cruise, el.spegel/fönster, alu.fälgar, c.lås, airbag, antispinn,  ABS, ute temp, radio, s/v-hjul, servo, creme skinn. automat. Pris 209.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>S8</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>850000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Audi S8, 4 dörrar, 40.000 km. 4x4, Tiptronic-aut., klimataut., ABS, el.fönster/speglar/säten, soltak, c.lås, servo, airbag, startspärr, antispinn, cruise., alu., träinred., sort skinn, mitttarmstöd., sportssäten, stereo, alarm, s/v-hjul, dragkrok, 17"+18"alu. Pris 850.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Yamaha</name>
        <model>Thunderace 1000</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>130000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Yamaha Thunderace 1000, 11.500 km. Röd/Silver,tankväska medföljer. 146hk Pris kan diskuteras vid snabb affär. Pris 130.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>A4 1.6</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>260000</price>
        <adtext>2000 Audi A4 1.6, 4 dörrar, 78.000 km. el.fönster, ABS, alu. airbag, , klima, ESP, navig. plus, TV, evt. inbyte, power box (+30 HK) medföljer. Pris 260.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Jeep</name>
        <model>Grand Cherokee 2.5TD</model>
        <regyear>0</regyear>
        <price>359000</price>
        <adtext>0 Jeep Grand Cherokee 2.5TD, Stv., 38.000 km. A/C, el.fönster/spegel, 8xalu., c.lås, airbag, R/CD, s/v-hjul, servo. Pris 359.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>TL 1000 R</model>
        <regyear>1998</regyear>
        <price>110000</price>
        <adtext>1998 Suzuki TL 1000 R, 8400 km. Pris 110.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Volkswagen</name>
        <model>Golf 1.8 Pink Floyd</model>
        <regyear>1994</regyear>
        <price>85000</price>
        <adtext>1994 Volkswagen Golf 1.8 Pink Floyd, 4 dörrar, 135.600 km. Eu-godkänd, airbag, el.taklucka, just ratt, metallic, radio/CD/Kass, s/v-hjul, servicebok, servo, stereo. Fullständig service, 1 ägare, 6 högtalare. Pris 85.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>4 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Volvo</name>
        <model>850 2.0 LT</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>245490</price>
        <adtext>1997 Volvo 850 2.0 LT, Stv., 122785 km. halvskinn, el.spegel/fönster/soltak, fj.c.lås, st.spärr, airbag, just.ratt, rails, nedf.baksäte, m.armstöd, ABS, rad/kass, alarm, dragkrok, s/v-hjul, f.glass, met, garanti, servo. Pris 245.490 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Audi</name>
        <model>A3 1.6 Ambition</model>
        <regyear>1998</regyear>
        <price>180000</price>
        <adtext>1998 Audi A3 1.6 Ambition, 3 dörrar, 88.000 km. s/v-hj. el.fönster, ABS, f.glass, alu. c.lås, servo, airbag, rökfri, stilig bil. Pris 180.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>3 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>BMW</name>
        <model>K 1200 RS</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>195000</price>
        <adtext>2000 BMW K 1200 RS, 4.000 km. sidoväskor, bagagefästen. Pris 195.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>1200</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>Baleno 1.6 GLX</model>
        <regyear>1999</regyear>
        <price>175000</price>
        <adtext>1999 Suzuki Baleno 1.6 GLX, Stv., 49.500 km. A/C, el.fönster/speil, c.lås, airbag, rails, ABS, stereo, , servo. Pris 175.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>LS 650 Savage</model>
        <regyear>1987</regyear>
        <price>29000</price>
        <adtext>1987 Suzuki LS 650 Savage, röd. Pris 29.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020116</addate>
        <volume>650</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Suzuki</name>
        <model>GS 500 E</model>
        <regyear>1993</regyear>
        <price>31900</price>
        <adtext>1993 Suzuki GS 500 E. Pris 31.900,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020117</addate>
        <volume>500</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>BMW</name>
        <model>520 i</model>
        <regyear>2000</regyear>
        <price>387000</price>
        <adtext>2000 BMW 520 i, Stv., 52.600 km. Skinn, klima, m.f.ratt, el.spegel/fönster, alu.fälgar, c.lås, airbag x 6, antispinn, rails, träint, ABS, rad/cd, alarm, dragkrok, met, servo, Pris 387.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Triumph</name>
        <model>Daytona T 595</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>115000</price>
        <adtext>1997 Triumph Daytona T 595, 13.000 km. Är som ny, karbon anlägg, nya däck, extra tank. Pris 115.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>955</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Mitsubishi</name>
        <model>Pajero 2.5 TD</model>
        <regyear>1987</regyear>
        <price>59000</price>
        <adtext>1987 Mitsubishi Pajero 2.5 TD, Stv. 4x4, dragkrok, servo, mycket utr., ingen rost. Pris 59.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
    </ad>
</autoads>
```

What I would like to do is extract all the Suzuki cars and have a numeric order for each. In which order they are extracted does not matter, that is why I do not use an sortby function in my XSLT.

This is how far I've gotten with my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Fordonsannonser för Suzuki</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="autoads/ad">
      <xsl:if test="name = 'Suzuki'">
        <tr> 
          <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/> Suzuki  <xsl:value-of select="model"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="regyear"/> modell</td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/> kronor</td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Almost complete the only thing that is missing the the numeric function from 1,2,3,4. I do get an extraction which counts like the below html example 8->13 and so on.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>Fordonsannonser f&ouml;r Suzuki</h2>
      <table>
         <tr></tr>
         <tr>
            <td>8 Suzuki  TL 1000 R</td>
            <td>1998 modell</td>
            <td>110000 kronor</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>13 Suzuki  Baleno 1.6 GLX</td>
            <td>1999 modell</td>
            <td>175000 kronor</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>14 Suzuki  LS 650 Savage</td>
            <td>1987 modell</td>
            <td>29000 kronor</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>15 Suzuki  GS 500 E</td>
            <td>1993 modell</td>
            <td>31900 kronor</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Can someone use this example and explain how I can extract with the Position function an numeric value which goes from 1,2,3,4 etc or the "number" method. Does not matter for me just need this clarified.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position()` function returns the position of the *current node* in the *[current node list](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#dt-current-node-list)*. Your current node list is established by your `xsl:for-each` instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="autoads/ad">
```

which selects **all** ads in the input XML.

In order to include only the wanted ads in the current node list, change your selection to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="autoads/ad[name='Suzuki']">
```

Then you won't need the `xsl:if` instruction.

Comment: WoW Thanks this worked really simple, damn feel kinda stupid now. 
Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<xsl:for-each select="autoads/ad">
      <xsl:if test="name = 'Suzuki'">
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each select="autoads/ad[name = 'Suzuki']">
```

Comment: Thanks mate for the assist!